Outside GFI not working
So, I bought a house and checked all power outlets and they work, except the GFI outside on the eve. There is a switch inside by the front door that controls the eve outlet. I went to reset the GFI and it would not reset. No clicking or power to it. Checked no power going to the outlet at all. Should I check the switch by the front door. All the other GFI’s in the garage work fine. and throughout the house. There’s two Romex lines coming into that GFI circuit. Neither one are offering any power common connected to green screw, two black that is power,one white you troll that is pigtail to one of the black. However, I checked power from all those lines individually and nothing is offering power. do you think it’s the switch in by the front door.

Yes, it could be that switch. Check it. If that doesn't explain/solve the problem, upload pictures of all relevant wiring. And is there anything else on the circuit? Have you checked the breaker?

did you check if that is a 3way switch
